# implementation search function

Tags: javascript, html, full-text-search, search-engine

I am developping a client side application with HTML5

my datas (only text data) are stored in my file JSON (70 Mega).

I want to implement a function to search all occurences in my data file.

Does exists open source of this function? or what is the best way to implement it?

thanks for your opinions

Comment: Search using what? Node.js on a server? JavaScript on the client side? Another server-side language?

Comment: please give example of what kind of data you would like to search and what is your JSON file format

Comment: I defined a variable in json file:
var myDatas =
[
    {
        "id" : "0000000001",
        "title" :"Data1",
        "info":
        {
            "info1": "data data data",
            "info2": "infoinfoiinfoinfo",
            "info3": "info333333333",
            "miscellaneous": "",
            "other":
                    [
                        {"title": "qwe", "ref": "other"},
                        {"title": "sdsd", "ref": "other"},
                        {"title": "ddd", "ref": "123"}
                    ]
        },
  "text": "xxxx text sldjdjskldj text  text"
 },


. . .
];

Answer (score 2):

If you are planning to use Javascript on the client side, take a look at http://kiro.me/projects/fuse.html

However,70Mb of data is simply too much for any browser to handle and a client side search implementation is definitely not recommended.

Comment: "70Mb of data is simply too much for any browser to handle" Yep, and thick about the time needed for every down- and upload.

Comment: FuseJS is currently in alpha. This means that the API is incomplete, buggy, and not intended for production use.